# почему я не могу создать этот массив?

Tags: c++

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<cmath>
#pragma comment(lib,"opengl32.lib")
using namespace std;

bool number_fibonachi(int a)
{
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, temp;
    if (a > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            if (n2 + n1 == a)
            {
                return true;
            }

            n1 = n1 + n2;
            n2 = n1 - n2;
            if (n2 + n1 > a)
            {
                return false;
            }
        } while (n2 + n1 <= a);
    }
    else if (a == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    float R = 0.5;
    int N;
    cout << "input N" << endl;
    cin >>  N;
    int size = 4 * N;

    POINTFLOAT vertices[size];
    vertices[0].x = 0;
    vertices[0].y = 1;
    vertices[1].x = -0.5;
    vertices[1].y = 0;
    vertices[2].x = 0.5;
    vertices[2].y = 0;
```

компилятор выдает C++ выражение должно иметь константное значение значение переменная (объявлено в
строке 44) невозможно использовать как константу

Comment: По стандарту. Стандарт требует знания размера массива во время компиляции.

Comment: так я определяю размер перед созданием массива.int size = 4 * N; если это не подходит то как иначе определить размер массива??

Comment: Вы его определяете **во время выполнения**, а надо - **во время компиляции**. Вы же не вводите `N` при компиляции? :)  Воспользуйтесь массивом в динамической памяти или, например вектором.

Comment: Массив размера - известного в run-time, можно в C, но нельзя в C++. Вероятно вы скопировали пример для другого языка.